# Good book on analytic continuation?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, divergent-series

For my Bachelor's thesis, I am investigating divergent series summation methods. One of those is analytic continuation. There are quite a few books on complex analysis that include a chapter or two on analytic continuation, but I would like to study this phenomenon in more detail. Could you please suggest a book on analytic continuation? Or a book on complex analysis with a heavy focus on analytic continuation?

Comment: Narasinham´s book on complex analysis and Foster´s book on Riemann surfaces, mainly the first one.

Comment: Would a book by G.H. Hardy on Divergent Series be something you were already familiar with? (Also, Dirichlet Series by Hardy is free at archive.org). Something of a long shot might be "Zetafuktionen und Quadratische Korper" by Don Zagier.

Comment: @Alan Jup, I am familiar with Hardy's book. I will check out the book by Zagier, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I found the book of K. Knopp much more readable than G.H.Hardy's and has exercises. However it is a bit old and the newest entry is Euler- and Borel-summation. The specific term "analytic continuation" (and examples) I've found in more contemporary sources much better explained.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Thank you for the suggestion!